# How are Badass Tokens infinite?

Tags: borderlands-2

I see [that](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Badass_Rank) "to acquire a new Badass Token, each Badass Token will require a greater number of Badass Ranks than the previous one. However, there is no limit to the number of Badass Ranks and Tokens that can be earned."

However, what happens once all challenges are completed (5/5 resp 1/1)? Apparently the challenge is just grayed out and does not indicate any further progress, so it seems like there is an upper limit to the number of tokens.

Do I possibly silently acquire more tokens even after 'officially finishing' a challenge?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tokens are theoretically infinite* (it's probably a 32 bit int or something unfeasible to actually fill, anyway). You can reset challenges on a character you've completed more than 80% of challenges on, so you can always earn more tokens, even with a limited set of characters.

You do NOT silently aquire more tokens after completing a certain challenge; rank 5 is the highest rank for any single challenge. There are however a LOT of challenges so it's easy to get tokens without realizing it.

Comment: Does resetting challenges clear your perks?

Comment: @MBraedley no, it resets challenges for that character only, not badass ranks or tokens.

Comment: I speak from experience btw, my siren has reset challenges

Comment: Thanks, I have never heard that such a reset is possible. So the rank is in fact infinite even with only a single character.

Comment: It was added in a sort-of recent update. There's instructions on the baddass rank screen I think. X to reset or something

Answer (score 1):

I think I just found the answer as I wrote the question, but I'm not really sure, please let me know if I'm mistaken.

After starting a new character, the challenge status of a previous character is not used again. So each new character can complete all challenges again, gaining more tokens. Since it is possible to create an infinite amount of characters, one may gain infinite tokens this way.